# Using PHP to add current page class

Tags: php

I created a config.php file that defines the URL for the site, I also created a variable for the template URL "/_inc" both using DEFINE. I call these variables in functions.php successfully, I then created a function to display the URL, I include the functions.php file into my header.php and then include that elswhere.

Everything works fine but I am trying to use the function in an if statement to add a current_page_item class to nav links. I am currently using the following code which is not working because I have it coded incorrectly. I need to know the correct coding procedure.

```
<?php if(site_url(). '/index.php') { echo 'current_page_item'; } ?>
```

Comment: " is not working" Is not an error message not a problem description.

Comment: Ok, the code above is flawed. I am not sure where it is flawed however, the function "site_url()" returns the URL for the base directory, the domain name itself.

Comment: Your `if` statement will always evaluate to TRUE, which begs the question: why have the `if` there at all?

Comment: @JonahBishop I need to have an IF statement to check if the current URL is at /index.php and if it is then display the "current_page_item", unless you know a better way.

Comment: I see. You are using the wrong operator. The `.` operator appends strings together. Use `==` instead (as the answer below shows).

Comment: @JonahBishop That operator still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also declaring variables while including the header.php. I used the following code to fix this problem.

```
<?php if($get_page_name == 'Home') echo 'current_page_item'; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function should return just the part of the URL after the domain root (from the first slash on). Then you could do this:

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == site_url() . 'index.php') { echo 'current_page_item'; }
```

I'm assuming your current function returns the full URL. You're just taking it, concatenating it with index.php, and not comparing it with anything. You have to compare it with the current URL provided by php.

Comment: Please let me know if this works. If it does, I'd change the question title to "How to match current URL in PHP?"

Comment: That still doesn't work, and I already created a function that gets the URL of the site.

Comment: What do you get when you print out the return value of your function? Try something like: `$value = site_url(); die("Value: $value");` That should tell you what's being returned. My guess is that it isn't what you expect.

Comment: I called the function itself on the page.

Comment: <?php site_url(); ?> and it returns with the domain URL fine.

Comment: Im using this functions for the links in the navigation.